# ct100_ContentPlaceholder1 does not work when hosting App on IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I am having trouble with running Javascript code on my ASP.Net application when hosting it on IIS. It works just fine when I run locally. I set Authentication to anonymous and turned on Static content. I put a `Console.log("BeginningScriptTest")` on my script and it registers. I narrowed it down to ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1 and I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')` I also added `ControlIDMode="Static"` in my form.

Parent Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        btnFromDate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('Calender.aspx?textbox=txtFromDate','SelectDate','width=250,height=280,left=570,top=250');");
        btnToDate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('Calender.aspx?textbox=txtToDate','SelectDate','width=250,height=280,left=570,top=250');");
    }
```

Child Code:

```
protected void GetDateCal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["textbox"] != "")
        {
            string strScript = "console.log('BeginningScriptTest');window.opener.document.forms[0].ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + Request.QueryString["textbox"].ToString() + ".value = '";
            strScript += GetDateCal.SelectedDate.ToString();
            strScript += "';window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();console.log('EndScriptTest');";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( this.GetType(), "Calendar_ChangeDate", strScript, true);

        }

    }
```

When I inspect the webpage using my DevTools, I can clearly see the script being registered.

```
<form method="post" action"./Calender.aspx?textbox=txtFromDate" id="form1">
    <div class=aspNetHidden">...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
console.log('BeginningScriptTest');window.opener.document.forms[0].ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate.value = '12/9/2022 12:00:00 AM';window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();console.log('EndScriptTest');//]]>
    </script>
    <div class="aspNetHidden">...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</form>
```

On my Console on IIS, I can it hitting my `console.log('BeginningScriptTest')`, and then followed by `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')`.

Comment: I could see that your JS code tries to assign a value on the new window and submit the form. I would suggest try to check and confirm that the webpage in the new window loaded completely before you run your JS code. If the page is not loaded, then you could wait to get it load and then run your JS code. If the page is not loaded and you try to find controls and assign the value, but the control is not available then you will receive an error.

Comment: The pages are loaded. It's a calendar form that sends a date back to my parent text box. Once I click on a date, it fires off the javascript code and the script is added to the form. From what I see on the Network tab, it will blink with the action "pending" and then disappear. I'm guessing that's where the Type error happens.

Comment: Do you mean the page or some file is pending to load while you check the Network tab?  I would suggest manually try to run the JS code when the new window page is loaded. further check the control you are trying to find is available on that window. check whether your JS code able to reference `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate`

Comment: No, everything is loaded on the page already. The pending comes after I click on a date which fires off the script with ```ct100_ContentPlaceholder```, and then I get the TypeError

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It's not a permanent solution because it does not work locally, but it works when it is deployed on the IIS.

I realized that my parent code took on an ID of `ContentPlaceHolder_txtFromDate` instead of `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtFromDate` so I removed the `ctl00_` prefix from my script.

I am very confused so if someone can please explain it to me that would be great.

```
    <div class=aspNetHidden">...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
console.log('BeginningScriptTest');window.opener.document.forms[0].ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate.value = '12/9/2022 12:00:00 AM';window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();console.log('EndScriptTest');//]]>
    </script>
    <div class="aspNetHidden">...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</form>
```

Comment: On your dev machine, could you please check the ID of the date textbox in your Asp.net project in Visual Studio? Check what ID it has?

Comment: It has the ID of ```ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate```. But when I deploy it on the IIS, it has the ID of ```ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate```

Comment: My dev machine will only work with the prefix ```ctl00``` in front.